# What does "ed" mean in a JLabel constraint?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, miglayout

#### Background

I am working on some code written by someone no longer at the company where I work, and I'm trying to figure out how he has written the constraints on a label.

I have very little experience working with GUI so I'm trying to figure out what's going on.

#### What I've tried

I've looked on a couple of references... http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/cheatsheet.html
http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html ...

and I *just about* understand the syntax in this line:

```
  this.add(new JLabel(icon), "pos (ed" + i + ".x-pref) (ed" + i + ".y)");
```

except for the `ed` parts. What purpose is `ed` serving in this line?

Comment: That references a GUI element and `ed" + i + ".x-pref` generates a name. The result could e.g. `ed1.x-pref`

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure what you mean. Does this mean there would be preset constraints called ed1.x-pref, ed2.x-pref, ed3.x-pref etc., and as the code iterates i++ then the icons will be placed in those positions?

Comment: Without knowing the code, yes that's what I would assume.

Comment: OK, that's enough for me to go with to investigate a bit further. Thanks. Do you want to post as an answer so that I can mark as answered?